# Video Paused when change Activity in Andorid Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I have 2 Activities: Countdown Activity and Video Activity

I wanna the video play automatically after the countdown

Countdown Activity > Video A Activity > Countdown Activity > Video B Activity > Countdown Activity > Video C Activity

The first Video, it can play properly after countdown. But, Second and third one just paused and not play automatically after the countdown.

This is what I do for the Intent in Countdown Activity.

```
if (typeActivity == FIRST_VIDEO_START){
                    VideoActivity.launchIntent(selectedVideo, this@CountdownActivity)
                    this@CountdownActivity.finish()
                } else {
                    this@CountdownActivity.finish()
                }
```

Any suggestion Guys ? Thanks in Advance

Comment: You need to pass down the current time of the player in the next activity and in the next activity when OnPrepared() is called seek video to passed current time.

Comment: https://github.com/danikula/AndroidVideoCache  Also integrate this video cache so that your video pause and play transition looks better.